# Suggestions for existing wiki-like markdown project

Tags: php, markdown, wiki

I have used [TikiWiki](http://info.tiki.org/Tiki+Wiki+CMS+Groupware) for a while and recently tried [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki), but either of them seems to be too complex for my simple need.

To be honest, I prefer markdown over wiki syntax for it's simplicity, thus why I'm asking this question :

I am looking for a collaborative documentation system based on markdown syntax like the Github's wiki system.

- This project should be written in PHP so it can be served on a shared hosting (ie. should be installable and standalone).
- Images and other medias are optional, but it would mainly be used to document code and programming related projects.
- May use MySQL or PostgreSQL.
- An extension system is not *necessary*.
- Optionally, a possibility to make pages visible or hidden (draft?).

Can someone suggest an/such existing project?

Comment: I'd like to find this too. The blog-like format for logging technical and coding work feels too feint, but Markdown is a definite given!

Comment: I could start my own project with these base requirements. However I already have a dozen projects in mind, a pretty loaded schedule and if something already exists, why bother? Most projects do not turn out on Google as they are very specific. I'm hoping the community do know something like this exists. Otherwise, it's amazing no such project has been thought and built before!

Comment: Its a pity my host doesn't offer Ruby, else I'd set up Octopress, Github's own page generator. Then again I ran into dependency issues setting up locally, likely from my sid distro.

Comment: I totally have no idea how are this wikis coded, but if they are good, you should be able to change some WikiParser class (that turns Wiki markup into html) with a MarkdownParser (that turns markdown markup into html). Of course, the fact that nobody knows it it's a symptom that maybe they are not the best code-bases in the world.

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós, the problem with most Wiki projects is that they are just terrible and often bloated with features. Changing a parser would require a bit more work than just converting a data form submission. I don't care much about all the features offered with TikiWiki (especially not impressed by their upgrade system) and I'm not satisfied with other projects like MediaWiki (ie. how they do things under the hood, API wise, etc.). Certainly, there must exist something else, better, using markdown, which someone, somewhere should be aware, have tested, and can offer feedback for. No?

Comment: Really? "not constructive"? This question was written carefully to avoid debate (I'm not asking for preferences, or what is better, but a list of projects fitting some generic requirements), expecting links to such projects (references), based on user experience (specific expertise), etc. SO is not only about "Help me with my code"!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [DokuWiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki). It has his own syntax, but with the [Markdown-Plugin](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin%3amarkdownextra) it also understands Markdown files (It uses the [PHP Markdown Extra](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/) library.). The wiki articles are stored directly in the filesystem, no database is needed. There exists also some Git plugins for DokuWiki.

Another solution would be a document generator like [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) that reads text in the Restructured Text Format (more powerful than Markdown) and writes static HTML pages.

Answer (score 2):

I have also used a lot TiddlyWiki (and contributed to it too) and switched to DokuWiki for a hosted wiki. Finally I developed my own project, I use on a daily base for 6 month.

Have a look at [NotewikiApp](http://notewiki.bidix.info/) : **A wiki webapp for Google App Engine as a notebook**

**Notewiki** is a wiki designed to take notes and organized them as in a notebook. The wiki space is divided in private and public areas to share some notes and to hide others.

**Notewiki App** is implemented in Python for Google App Engine and uses Markdown syntax. This web app is in beta stage (version 0.3). It is published at [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/notewikiapp). A package is ready for installation in your own Google Apps domain.

The Notewiki App interface is compatible with iPhone to access and edit notes everywhere.

Comment: interesting. I'll take a look at it.